# PostgreSQL error: subquery must return only one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgis, postgresql-9.2

Using PostgreSQL-9.1 and PostGIS 2.0.1, when doing a SELECT query containing a sub-query that returns multiple columns, I am getting the error `subquery must return only one column`.

How can the query/subquery be modified to return multiple columns?

**Query**

```
SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom,
        (SELECT g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom)
        FROM stage.dogs as g
        LIMIT 1)

FROM stage.users As l
```

---

**Full Query**

```
SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom,
    g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom) 
FROM stage.users As l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
    FROM stage.dogs as g
    ORDER BY g.geom <-> l.geom 
    LIMIT 1) as g
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "l"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "l", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom,
       g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom)
FROM stage.users As l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM stage.dogs LIMIT 1) as g
```

This is literally what you had (assuming stage.dogs) is not empty. Not sure if there should be a correlation between `users` and `dogs` though.

---

To find the closest dog to a user, you can use this query. The scalar subquery finds the dog's ID, and is joined back to the table to retrieve the other columns.

```
SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom,
       g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom)
FROM (
    SELECT l1.*, (SELECT g1.id
                  FROM stage.dogs as g
                  ORDER BY g.geom <-> l.geom 
                  LIMIT 1) g_id
    FROM stage.users As l1
) l
JOIN stage.dogs as g ON g.id = l.g_id;
```

Fair warning that this will NOT be a fast query.

---

At the risk of performing even slower, see query below for multiple tables

```
SELECT l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom,
       g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom) dog_distance,
       c.id, c.lat, c.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, c.geom) cat_distance,
       b.id, b.lat, b.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, b.geom) bird_distance
FROM (
    SELECT l1.*, (SELECT g1.id
                  FROM stage.dogs as g1
                  ORDER BY g1.geom <-> l.geom 
                  LIMIT 1) dog_id,
                 (SELECT c1.id
                  FROM stage.cats as c1
                  ORDER BY c1.geom <-> l.geom 
                  LIMIT 1) cat_id,
                 (SELECT b1.id
                  FROM stage.cats as b1
                  ORDER BY b1.geom <-> l.geom 
                  LIMIT 1) bird_id
    FROM stage.users As l1
) l
LEFT JOIN stage.dogs as g ON g.id = l.dog_id
LEFT JOIN stage.dogs as c ON c.id = l.cat_id
LEFT JOIN stage.dogs as b ON b.id = l.bird_id;
```

Comment: I tried expanding the query (updated question) and now theres the error `ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "l"`
`Hint: There is an entry for table "l", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

Comment: For the second query, it took 200ms to return 500 rows. However like Erwin's answer, this query returned the `g.geom` that was furthest away from each `l.geom`. Then again maybe I am using the wrong CRS? Both`geom` cols are currently `POINT,2163`

Comment: Clutching straws here, try `ORDER BY ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom)` in the subquery?

Comment: I discovered there was an error with the coordinate system used. How do you extend the query to also select the closest geometry from more tables, eg: `cats`, `birds` etc

Answer (score 2):

This gives you one row per user with the closest dog:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (l.id)
       l.id, l.lat, l.lng, l.geom
      ,g.id, g.lat, g.lng, ST_Distance(l.geom, g.geom) 
FROM   stage.users     l
CROSS  JOIN stage.dogs g
ORDER  BY l.id, (l.geom <-> g.geom)
```

More information on the technique with [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in this related answer:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

I guess if you have [**GiST index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/gist.html) on `g.geom`, the planner might be smart enough to just pick the closes item from it. Not sure, didn't test. Otherwise, this kind of `CROSS JOIN` would result in O(N²) and performance may get out of hand quickly with a bigger table.

I quote the Postgis manual [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html):

> Index only kicks in if one of the geometries is a constant (not in a
>   subquery/cte). e.g. `'SRID=3005;POINT(1011102 450541)'::geometry` instead of `a.geom`

So you may be out of luck here.

According to the manual you may need to order by `ST_Distance()` to get precise sort order, but you shouldn't be getting the one furthest away. That makes no sense.

Comment: I may be wrong, but this query returned the `g.geom` that was the furthest away from the corresponding `l.geom`. Query took about 8 seconds to return 500 rows. Looks likst GiST index was not used.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer.